# Escaping double dollar signs in password in AZ CLI in PowerShell shell

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to run the `az sql db export` command and it requires a SQL Admin username and password. Our password happens to have two dollar signs in it e.g. ABC$$123==). So when I run the following command (with valid values in it, of course):

```
$pwd = "ABC$$123==)"
az sql db export -s myserver -n mydatabase -g mygroup -p $pwd-u login \
    --storage-key MYKEY== --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey \
    --storage-uri https://myAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/myBacpac.bacpac
```

I get this response:

```
')' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried so many variations of escaping this but haven't found the correct method that works. In the end, I plan to read the password from Azure Key Vault and was gonna pass it straight in to the az cli command. What do I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: ```"`"``` is the escape character? Do you want ```"ABC`$123==`)"```?

Comment: I tried this: $pwd = $pwd.Replace("$", "`$").Replace(")", "`)") and it did not work.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the backtick to display (thanks mini markdown) but I basically am trying to replace the dollar sign with a backtick and dollar sign. Same with the close parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of quotes in powershell - single and double. In the double quote, you can pass in variables. In a single quote, everything is literal. For cases like your password, I would recommend just using the literal:

```
$pwd = 'ABC$$123==)'
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It may pass muster with PowerShell, but I think az cli is causing the next level issue. Here's what works but only with string literals: `'ABC"$$123==)'`  However, I am pulling the password from Azure Key Vault. So I'm not clear how to escape this still.

Comment: I was trying to run `az keyvault secret set` setting the value with double quotes. Changing to single quotes fixed my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20972, setting the value with double quotes inside single quotes (one for PowerShell, one for Command Prompt) solved the issue for me:

For example:

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name SomeVault --name foobar --value '"abc123|whoami"'
```